# Different roc_auc scores in Mlxtend vs Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlxtend

I ran sequential feature selection (mlxtend) to find the best (by roc_auc scoring) features to use in a KNN. **However, when I select the best features** and run them back through sklearn knn with the same parameters, I get a much different roc_auc value (0.83 vs 0.67).

Reading through the mlxtend documentation, it uses sklearn roc_auc scoring, so I can't figure out why I am getting such different scores.

**Mlxtend**

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)

from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS


sfs1 = SFS(knn, 
           k_features=5, 
           forward=True, 
           floating=True, 
           verbose=2,
           scoring='roc_auc',
           cv=5)

sfs1 = sfs1.fit(X, y)
```

[image: sequential feature selection output]

**Sklearn**  *I took this from an sklearn example -- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html*

```
##KNN
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=False)
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4,weights='uniform')

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

i = 0
for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.3,
             label='ROC fold %d (AUC = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))

    i += 1

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
         label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
         label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
         lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
plt.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                 label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('KNN ROC')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

[image: Sklearn output]

OS: 10.14.6

Python: 3.6.8.final.0

Sklearn: 0.21.3

mlxtend: 0.17.0

Comment: Your first pipeline is a SequentialFeatureSelector followed by KNeighborsClassifier while in the second case this is just as KNeighborsClassifier. And in addition, you have different parameter (4 neighbors rule for the first one while 1 neighbors rule in the second).

Comment: Thank you for catching that neighbors rule in the second @glemaitre, unfortunately, when I receive the same score when I correct for this.       The basis for my question is that I'm using the same features that SFS selected, but it gives me a different ROC_AUC score and I can't figure out why that is (even when I correct the neighbor rule)

Comment: The first example does not make any cross-validation (you are feeding the full X) while the second one does cross-validation. In case you also do cross-validation also in the first case, ensure that you selected the same samples. Otherwise, the results will be different (which is not a big deal in practice, it give you info regarding the variation of the results).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help so far @glemaitre .    The first example using the same cross validation method ( StratifiedKFold -- based on the package's documentation) 5 times as does the second example (see cv=5). I get the exact same avg_score every time I run the first block of code, but I get different scores each time I run the second block of code.